# react-native run-android fails, could not install app

Tags: react-native

I m having a problem when I try to run my react-native application in my Android Device. The device is connected even when I make sure that it is.

> adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
>
> HMNBBCE6A2826109        device

Device: Huawei Y2
Android Version: 5.1
Debug mode: enbaled
the server is running.
When i run

> react-native run-android

I get this error

> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
> Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
> set up your Android development environment:
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem with my linux laptop.
I ran this inside my app root folder and worked:

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

You have to give permission on the `android/gradlew`.

I found the answer on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8868) github issue

And you must also do this:

Click [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) to see the all article on the react-native docs page (the place where i get this information).

> 3. Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable
>      The React Native tools require some environment variables to be set up in order to build apps with native code.
>      Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile config file:
>      `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`
>      `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`
>      `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
>
>    **.bash_profile is specific to bash. If you're using another shell, you will need to edit the appropriate shell-specific config file.**

Answer (score 4):

```
npx @react-native-community/cli doctor
```

This command checks your environment and displays a report of the status of `react-native` installation. Check the output carefully for other software you might need to install

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while and in my case (using Windows 10) the solution was to install [Java JRE and JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) even though I was already set up with Android Studio.

The problem got clearer when I created a new empty project with `create-react-native-app Example` and ran it with `react-native run-android`. The error then complained about JAVA_HOME variable.

Another good tip is to open up your project (located under "android"-folder in your react native project) in Android Studio and see if it compiles.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try the command.

```
adb devices
```

See if there is any devices listed.

If so check the local.properties file inside android folder and check the sdk defined is correct.

if there is no local.properties files. add a new file named local.properties with the following content

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Thu May 25 18:29:08 IST 2017
sdk.dir=path to sdk
```

This command will also help

```
 adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```