# Cannot build react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native and i try to create Awesome app follow 
[this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). But when I run `react-native run-android` it throw many error like this

```
    AAPT err(Facade for 762660807): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1110068242): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_1): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 146724770): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 286442752): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1478193577): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_3): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_2): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_4): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_5): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 1225942468): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
AAPT err(Facade for 2043292931): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
AAPT err(Facade for 1529341869): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Thread(png-cruncher_8): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Thread(png-cruncher_7): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_6): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 482911119): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
AAPT err(Facade for 1815908639): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1055339140): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_10): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
AAPT err(Facade for 1587857275): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_11): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 2122638962): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_9): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 1605821964): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Thread(png-cruncher_13): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Thread(png-cruncher_12): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_15): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 2112052223): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_14): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 1184088505): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 522173194): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1024149312): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
AAPT err(Facade for 1031795258): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_18): Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_16): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Thread(png-cruncher_17): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Thread(png-cruncher_20): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 278298510): /home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
Thread(png-cruncher_19): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:151)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.487 secs
```

I 've found many QA for this type of question like

- [cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158727/android-sdk-aapt-error-libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file)
- [react-native run-android fails, could not install app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360544/react-native-run-android-fails-could-not-install-app)

But it still not work :(. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check your home/trantuan/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt because the error tells that No such file or directory

Comment: @TentenPonce I checked, it has a "shared library" aapt there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be missing the libz.so library. 
From another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file), try:

> sudo apt-get install zlib1g

or

> sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386

Comment: I appreciate for your answer. With my case, it works with `sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386`. And after checked guide in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html), it have some more other required library: `libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386`